# Error jquery validation plugin depends. Form valid when fields are not valid

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

## Problem description

I have a web form wizard for which I need validation that supports (a) hidden fields and (b) conditional validation. Jquery seems the best fit. Once all is set up as follows (**simplified example**):

```
$( "form[name=form]" ).validate({
    ...
    ignore: [],
    rules: {
        'form[owner]': {
            required: true,
        },
        'form[bank_account]': {
            required: true, 
            depends: function(element){
                    return $('#my_select').is(':checked');`
    messages : {
        'form[owner]' : {
             required: "The owner is necessary",
        },
        'form[bank_account]' : {
            required: "This field must be filled out when switch on",
         },
    ...
})
```

## Error description

1. I force the validation to go wrong by submitting the form without filling out the fields listed above.
2. In my case, as there is a wizard, I output messages with an alert, for the errors are not visible at first.
3. I go back in the form, **fill out just owner**, and try to force again the validation to fail by submitting, with **my_select checked**
4. The validation is passed (and form submitted) although there is still a field which is not valid, resulting in an error on the server-side.

On javascript console, I got the following error:

> Cannot read property 'call' of undefined.  Exception occurred when checking element form[bank_account], check the method depends

## Expected result

All fields should be validated accordingly to form validation **each and every time the form is to be submitted**

**How can this be fixed?**

Comment: By "fill out just name" I assume you mean, that you entered the "owner"? Was "my_select" checked at the time of trying to force the validation after entering "owner"? Because if not, then the validation seems to work fine. Also, you might want to add a `}` at the end of `depends: function(element)`

Comment: Yes, I mean owner, and yes, my_select was checked. This is just example code I wrote ad-hoc. The essence of the problem was long tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I did not find any questions similar to mine around. The solution I found is the following:

Instead of using the `depends` method, use a function to establish if the field should or should not be required, including it in the conditions on which this operation should rely (i.e. if a checkbox is checked or not)

```
$( "form[name=form]" ).validate({
    ...
    ignore: [],
    rules: {
        'form[owner]': {
            required: true,
        },
        'form[bank_account]': {
            required: function(element){
                    return $('#my_select').is(':checked') && $('form_bank_account').val();
    messages : {
        'form[owner]' : {
             required: "The owner is necessary",
        },
        'form[bank_account]' : {
            required: "This field must be filled out when switch on",
         },
    ...
})
```

Either documentation is confusing, or the library has a bug.